# Passing observable's data to another, is nesting necessary?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have example of code:

```
private Observable<String> rxFetch() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> fetchWebsiteHtml())//fetch source of html
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, "Connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                .doOnNext(s ->
                        rxGetHotMovies(s)//fetch from html some html tags
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Parse list failed somehow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                })
                                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                                .doOnNext(
                                        hotMovies ->
                                                rxLoastToListView(hotMovies)//fill list with data
                                                        .doOnError(throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, "Filling list problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                                                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                                                        .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "rxFetch: xxxxxx"))
                                                        .subscribe()
                                )
                                .subscribe(hotMovies -> {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < hotMovies.size(); i++) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "fetch list item: " + hotMovies.get(i).toString());
                                    }
                                })
                );
    }
```

This observable `rxFetch` does:

1. download html source in separate thread
2. when error - shows error msg
3. when success -> onNext -> fetch html and obtain some html tags in separate thread
4. when error - show error msg
5. when success - pass data to listview and shows result in adapter

My question is: is nesting necessary when we operate on few observables when one of them returns necessary data for another? I would like to not nesting observables but the first one returns data - and imho it doesn't allow me to use for example zip, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way is like this:

```
private Observable<String> rxFetch() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> fetchWebsiteHtml())//fetch source of html
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnError(throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, "Connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .flatMap(s -> rxGetHotMovies(s)
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnError(throwable -> 
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Parse list failed somehow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .flatMap(hotMovies -> rxLoastToListView(hotMovies)
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnError(throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, "Filling list problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "rxFetch: xxxxxx"))
            .subscribe(hotMovies -> {
               for (int i = 0; i < hotMovies.size(); i++) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "fetch list item: " + hotMovies.get(i).toString());
             });
}
```

However, I'd suggest that you abstract away the error handling:

```
private static <T> Transformer<T, T> whenErrorToast(Function<E extends Throwable, String> messageComposer) {
   return source -> source.onErrorResumeNext(e -> Observable
       .just(messageComposer.apply(e))
       .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .doOnNext(msg -> Toast.makeText(this, msg Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .flatMap(msg -> Observable.empty());
}

private Observable<String> rxFetch() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> fetchWebsiteHtml())//fetch source of html
            .compose(whenErrorToast(e -> "Connection problem"))
            .flatMap(s -> rxGetHotMovies(s))
            .compose(whenErrorToast(e -> "Parse list failed somehow"))
            .flatMap(hotMovies -> rxLoastToListView(hotMovies))
            .compose(whenErrorToast(e -> "Filling list problem"))
            .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "rxFetch: xxxxxx"))
            .subscribe(hotMovies -> {
               for (int i = 0; i < hotMovies.size(); i++) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "fetch list item: " + hotMovies.get(i).toString());
             });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `flatMap` operator, which allows you to chain reactive streams.

I would rewrite your code in this way:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> fetchWebsiteHtml())
    .flatMap(s -> rxGetHotMovies(s))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(hotMovies -> {
        // update UI here
    }, throwable -> {
        // check throwable type and show appropriate error message
    });
```